# Pass return values as arguments between Backbone View methods

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, jquery

I am trying to make a little application with a view that handles `mousedown` and `mouseup` jQuery events.

I have a `getCoords` method that returns the coordinates of a given mouse event 
I call that method from `determineEvent`, and store the coordinates of the `mousedown` in `mouseDownCoords`. It also returns the `mouseDownCoords` variable. The purpose of this method is to distinguish between a click and a drag event, but I ommited the code for brevity)

The method `doStuff` is triggered on `mouseup` and stores the coordinates of the mouseup in `mouseUpCoords`. The problem is that I don't know how to access the mouseDownCoords variable from within this method.

I though of triggering the event manually, through code, but that doesn't make much sense (triggerring a mouseup event from a mousedown eventhandler...)
Also calling the `determineEvent` method from `doStuff`, doesn't make sense because I'm passing a different event to it (mouseup)

Here's my view code

```
var ScreenView = Backbone.View.extend({
  tagName: 'div',
  className:"screen",
  events: {
    "mousedown": "determineScreenEvent",
    "mouseup": "doStuff"
  },

  getCoords: function(e) {
    var screenOffset = this.$el.offset();
    var coords = [e.pageX - screenOffset.left, e.pageY - screenOffset.top];
    return coords;
  },

  determineEvent: function(e) {
    mouseDownCoords = this.getCoords(e);
    return mouseDownCoords;
    //code for distinguishing between click/drag
  },

  doStuff: function(e, mouseDownCoords) {
    mouseUpCoords = this.getCoords(e);
    //do stuff with mouseUpCoords and mouseDownCoords
  }

});
```

Any pointers would be helpful :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store it in the view if you want a quick solution:

```
determineEvent: function(e) {
  this.mouseDownCoords = this.getCoords(e);
  return this.mouseDownCoords;
  //code for distinguishing between click/drag
},

doStuff: function(e, mouseDownCoords) {
  var mouseUpCoords = this.getCoords(e);
  //use this.mouseDownCoords
  //do stuff with mouseUpCoords and mouseDownCoords
}
```

Comment: I do need a quick solution for moving on with other stuff, and thanx for providing that, but I can't accept your answer yet, as it doesn't seem optimal. Use @moon suggested that I should store the coords on a Model and retrieve them from there, but this is a dummy view and there is no model involved. Do you know if there is any middle-ground solution?

Comment: @IgnorantUser: There's nothing wrong with storing things in instance variables, there's no need for a model if you don't care about persistence or events. PS: You're missing a `var` or a `this.` in `doStuff`.

Comment: Accepting the solution provided, since there's no hard evidence on it being "wrong" (for the purpose I need). I'd like to use best practices as much as possible, but in the end it's too much overhead to create a model just for that data (which I'm throwing away in the end).
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

W.r.t Backbone you should have a Model attached to view that will contain the necessary data which is required to render the view.

I recommend that you should add a model to view and set these  `mouseDownCoords` and `mouseUpCoords` as part of that model that will be accessible within the view at any given time.

If your don't want to strictly follow Backbone way then simply store the coordinates as varibales in view but this is not recommended

Comment: The thing is that it's kind of a dummy view (no model involved).
I do understand that storing data in the view is not recommended, but are there any other alternatives? (besides having a model for the view)

Comment: What is the the problem with storing it in the view? (assuming that he does not want to sync this data to the server)

Comment: As far as MVC concerns the view should always have a model, in else case you will void the MVC paradigm.